# i cant setText in EditText

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> LOGCAT Erorrّّّ
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String a.thebook.m_Model.new_book1.getnamebook()' on a null
>   object reference

**in java Class**

```
package a.thebook;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import a.thebook.m_Model.new_book1;
....


public class my_book  extends AppCompatActivity {




    private new_book1 model;
    private EditText  bookname1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_book_activity);


        EditText bookname1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextbookname2);
         bookname1.setText(model.getbookname());
...



}
```

**get values from firebase Database.
 new_book1**

```
package a.thebook.m_Model;


import java.util.Objects;


public class new_book1 {


    public String author;
    public String bookname;

    public new_book1() {
    }
    public new_book1(String bookname ,String author) {
        this.bookname = bookname;
        this.author = author;

    }
    public String getauthor(int author) {

        return this.author;
    }
    public String getbookname() {

        return this.bookname;
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the initialization of `model`?

Comment: your model has empty text, you didnot set bookname and using getbookname directly

Comment: you are not initialize the class new_book1,
just created the reference

Answer (score 3):

You have not initialised your `model` variable. 
Hence you are getting a `null object` error.

Initialise your `new_book1` variable and your code will work

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_book_activity);
    model = new new_book1("abc","xyz");

    EditText bookname1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextbookname2);
     bookname1.setText(model.getbookname());

}
```

This will help you.

Comment: and don't forget to vote answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
private new_book1 model = new new_book1("myBook", "myself");
```

Comment: even this may give NPE , he should initialize like  `private new_book1 model = new new_book1("bookName","author");`